# How to set Fill color of Ellipse via Binding

Tags: c#, colors, wps

I want to  set Fill Color property of Ellipse via data binding, I have tried many ways so far was unsucessfull in setting it. Below is my XAML and VioewModel.cs code.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ClipEllipse" Fill="{Binding EllipseColor}"></Ellipse>        

public System.Windows.Media.Color EllipseColor
{
    get
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(255), (byte)r.Next(255), (byte)r.Next(255));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an exception (NOTE: binding exceptions are only visible in the debug trace if enabled in the settings) or do you get the same color all the time?

Comment: No color appears in Ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the data context ( which is your view model with property EllipseColor)

In code behind of xaml.cs file - try setting `DataContext=new ViewModel()` in constructor.